# For a international web application, which date format should I use?

Tags: date, datetime, web, datetime-format

I'm programming a website, that will have user from different parts of the world.
Which date format is the most recommended in this case ?

```
dd/mm/yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
yyyy/mm/dd
```

I know the right answer is "depends". What I need to know is the most commom for this kind of website.

Thanks!

Comment: You're own answer is correct: it depends. Mostly, it depends on what the user wants, so use a consistent timezone & format internally - I suggest UTC and 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and convert to what the user wants at output, either on the server, or by getting Javascript to use the user's machine settings.

Comment: If you use a format which uses the name, (or an abbreviation of the name) of the month rather that it's number then it will avoid any confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is neither of those suggested, but rather `YYYY-MM-DD` (dashes, not slashes). This is not region dependent, there is exactly one standard conformant way of denoting date, regardless of location, see [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)